# When does a power series decay at infinity?

Tags: power-series, analyticity, analytic-functions

Suppose I have a power series of infinite radius of convergence:
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nz^n.
$$
Is there a simple criterion on the $a_n$ that implies
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=0?
$$

Comment: Oops, yep thanks for spot.

Comment: I'll stick to $x$ when discussing real variables.

Comment: Perhaps you might require that $a_n$ can't all have the same sign

Comment: Can you show any example apart from $f(x)=0$ i.e. $a_n=0 \,\,\forall n$?

Comment: @Henry $f(z)=e^{-z}$ and $f(z)=e^{-z^2}$, the latter having zero limit as $x\to-\infty$, too.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - that is helpful

Comment: None of these are a nice sufficient condition though.